# How can I get the selected listview id (or name) without using javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, list-view

We have a listview button that executes javascript to obtain the **currently selected listview id** and passes that value to another VF page. We are planning on moving to Lightning soon and that will limit our options with JS on buttons. Is there another way to find out what the id (or name) is of the **currently selected** list view without using Javascript?

Here's the javascript that we currently use to determine the id of the selected list view:

```
var listview = document.getElementById("is:islv:inlineSchedulerListView:enhancedList_listSelect"); 
var listId = listview.options[listview.selectedIndex].value;
```

Thanks ahead of time. All suggestions are appreciated.